# I'd like to add Cors to this specific angular service that I have built How can I achieve this?

Tags: angular, service, cors, get-request, http-options-method

My angular service basically goes and retrieves a movie and it's details from an api. I believe it will work if not for this cors issue. I realize that there are many ways to get around cors but I really want the simplest way based upon what I already have. How can I achieve this?

service page.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 //Typescript custom enum for search tpes (optional)
 export enum SearchType{
 all = '',
 movie = 'movie',
 series = 'series',
 episode = 'episode'
 }


 @Injectable ({
 providedIn : 'root'
 })
 export class MovieService {
 url = 'http://www.omdapi.com/';
 apiKey = '*******' //my api key here!


 constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

 searchData(title: string, type: SearchType): 
 Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get(`${this.url}? 
 s=${encodeURI(title)}&type=${type}&apikey=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
  map(results => results['Search'])
  );
 }

  getDetais(id){
  return this.http.get(`${this.url}? 
  i=${id}&plot=full&apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
  }

 }
```

Here's the backend I got from a boilerplate. It currently just displays Api is running on port 9000. I'm not sure how to connect this to my front end so that cors isn't an issue.

main.js

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {Application} from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";

export function initServer() {

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app:Application = express();

app.use(cors());

app.route("/").get((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("<h1>API is up and running!</h1>");
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("HTTP REST API Server running at port " + PORT);
});

}
```

Comment: What's the point of showing the client code if you have a CORS problem? If you don't own the API, as seems likely, you need a proxy of some kind.

Comment: The issue I'm having is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. How can I add this header to my requested resource

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it's a headers issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't "get around" CORS. At least not by changing anything on the side of your frontend/Angular app. If your requests are getting rejected because of CORS (which I assume is the issue). You'll have to allow your domain on your backend and not your frontend.

Comment: the issue is that No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. How can I add this header to my requested resource

Comment: i think it's a headers issue

Comment: That error most likely means that your backend hasn't been setup to allow request coming from that domain. Could you provide some information about what you're using as your backend?

Comment: Here is my server.js file. It is basic but it runs
```import * as express from 'express';
import {Application} from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";

export function initServer() {

    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const app:Application = express();

    app.use(cors());

    app.route("/").get((req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send("<h1>API is up and running!</h1>");
    });


    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log("HTTP REST API Server running at port " + PORT);
    });

}```

Comment: Could you add this to your question? It's quite difficult to read as a comment

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes I can do that